# check which button called the activity to show respective SQLite row

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working with SQLite Database, I want to check which button was clicked to show respective table row, for example 1st button corresponds to 1st row and so  on. But the problem is, **it never shows the table elements**.

Here is the **Fragment** code that saves extra information about the button:

```
public class buttonsFragment extends Fragment {
    private Activity mActivity;

    private Button buttonAdd;
    private Button buttonAdd2;
    private Button buttonAdd3;
    static private final int BUTTON_1 = 1;
    static private final int BUTTON_2 = 2;
    static private final int BUTTON_3 = 3;

    DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(getActivity());

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = activity;

    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buttons, container, false);
        buttonAdd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonAdd2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        buttonAdd3 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button3);


        return view;


    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
        buttonAdd2.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
        buttonAdd3.setOnClickListener(btnListener);

    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == BUTTON_1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && !data.getStringExtra("Goal").isEmpty()) {

            buttonAdd.setText(data.getStringExtra("Goal"));
        }

        if (requestCode == BUTTON_2 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && !data.getStringExtra("Goal").isEmpty()) {
            buttonAdd2.setText(data.getStringExtra("Goal"));
        }

        if (requestCode == BUTTON_3 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && !data.getStringExtra("Goal").isEmpty()){
            buttonAdd3.setText(data.getStringExtra("Goal"));
        }
    }




    private View.OnClickListener btnListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddGoalActivity.class);

            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.button:

                    intent.putExtra("called", "button1");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, BUTTON_1);
                    break;

                case R.id.button2:

                    intent.putExtra("called", BUTTON_2);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, BUTTON_2);
                    break;

                case R.id.button3:

                    intent.putExtra("called",BUTTON_3);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, BUTTON_3);
                    break;

            }

        }
    };



}
```

Here is the **Activity** code that has to insert and show the data to and from the database:

```
public class AddGoalActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText editText;
    Button buttonAdding;
    Spinner spinner;
    Spinner spinner2;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    String spinner_value1;
    String spinner_value2;



    String taskName = ""; 
    int startMonth, endMonth;

    ArrayAdapter<String> months1;
    Button buttonUpdate;
    DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(this);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_goal2);



        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddText);
        buttonAdding = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        buttonUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

       String called_from = getIntent().getStringExtra("called");
        if ("button1".equalsIgnoreCase(called_from)){

                Task t = dbHandler.getTask(1);
                editText.setText(t.getTaskName());
                spinner.setSelection(t.getStartMonth());
                spinner2.setSelection(t.getEndMonth());

        }



            Resources res = getResources();

            months1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    res.getStringArray(R.array.months_list));
            ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.months_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


    }


    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonAdd:
                putTextOnButton();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonUpdate:
               // updateTask();
                putTextOnButton();
                break;
        }



    }

    public void putTextOnButton () {

        startMonth = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        endMonth = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        taskName = editText.getText().toString();


        if (!taskName.isEmpty() && startMonth != 0 && endMonth!=0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(AddGoalActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            dbHandler.addTask(new Task(taskName, startMonth, endMonth));
            i.putExtra("Goal", taskName);
            setResult(AddGoalActivity.RESULT_OK, i);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

}
```

Here is the Dbhandler Class:

```
public DBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_TASKS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TASKS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_START + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_END + " TEXT " + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TASKS_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TASKS);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addTask(Task task) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //values.put(KEY_ID, task.getId());
    values.put(KEY_NAME, task.getTaskName());
    values.put(KEY_START, task.getStartMonth());
    values.put(KEY_END, task.getEndMonth());

    db.insert(TABLE_TASKS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public Task getTask(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TASKS, new String[]{KEY_ID,
                    KEY_NAME, KEY_START, KEY_END}, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Task task = new Task(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1),cursor.getInt(2),cursor.getInt(3) );

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return task;
}
```

}

Comment: so please add your code for dbHandler!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
   Intent i=getIntent();
int called_from =i.getIntExtra("called",100)
if (called_from == 100) {
        return;
    }

    if (called == (1)){

            Task t = dbHandler.getTask(1);
            editText.setText(t.getTaskName());
            spinner.setSelection(t.getStartMonth());
            spinner2.setSelection(t.getEndMonth());

    }
```

Comment: there is no any difference, It still does not implement set functions. Btw what's the point of 100 here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing setting the Listener you initialised to your buttons:

```
Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);

button1.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
button2.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
button3.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
```

Comment: no I did that, there is no error, it just doesn't do what what I want it to do, get the task by id, and show it's elements

Answer (score 0):

The issue is of fragment here. Because u are calling those button listeners in fragments. Can u share both the fragment and activity code.

Comment: Can you specify what do you mean?